# How to redirect to another page through JS (sending parameters)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to redirect to another page through JS(sending parameters)

I made the following code to that purpose, it does redirect and the requested page loads up 'ok'

```
window.location.replace(`http://10.0.30.11:3000/ProteseWEB/pages/detail/${path}?id=${param}`)
```

The problem is: When the requested page opens, it display an 404 not found on the network tab.

I don't understand why this is occuring, since the page I want is loaded 'perfectly'

[The error on the network tab:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAMJZ.png)

Edit(1)

@jlemley and @James Thank you for your answer!!! 
Indeed the 404 request and the URL that I requested were different. So I changed the function a little bit.

Here's the code:

```
openPageDetail = function (path, params, method = 'POST') {
    let iplocal = 'http://10.0.30.11:3000/ProteseWEB/pages/detalhe/'
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.method = method;
    form.action = iplocal + path;

    for (const key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
            hiddenField.name = key;
            hiddenField.value = params[key];
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

I tried to make it as a form submit, still, the error occurs

In addition, there's how I call for this function.
I have a DataTable and when the user double click a row, it opens up a detail page for the desired record.

```
    $('.table').on('dblclick', function(e) {
        if ((!(e.target.classList.contains('sorting_asc'))) && (!(e.target.classList.contains('sorting_desc')))) {
            openPageDetail('contas-a-pagar', {
                id: e.target.parentElement.id
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It may be helpful to include a complete snippet of your code so that we can see exactly what you are including. It's also interesting that the item that is showing a 404 does not look like the URL you mentioned. Does that happen even when you access the targeted page directly?

Comment: The url displayed in the network tab is not the same format as what you have posted.  Perhaps the server is 404ing on the original request and then redirecting you to another page that loads perfectly.

Comment: @jlemley I updated the question, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @James Thanks for pointing out this, I updated the code on the question.

Comment: @jlemley Yes. Even when I access the page directly, this error just come up. I'm wondering why only the detail pages have this problem, all the others are fine

Comment: Do you have a rewrite rule (e.g. .htaccess)?